# Can I mix Client-Side-Rendering and Server-Side-Rendering in AngularJS? and How?

Tags: angularjs, server, rendering, single-page-application

I'm building a Web site which is **not SPA**(single page app).

It would have **several pages** and I want to change current page **partially**. That is why I want to use Client-side rendering. But, it also has totally different pages which will be rendered by Server.

Each page will be changed partially by client-side-rendering and when user want to move to another page, server will render it. Is it possible?

So, my question is that **Can I mix Client-Side-Rendering and Server-Side-Rendering in AngularJS?**

And **how to render AngularJS on server side?**

Comment: You can't render AngularJS on server side. AngularJS runs in the browser! If you really want to mix, I would recommend looking at Jade Templating, and let express.js send the jade renderings back to your browser and/or angular.

Comment: @SirBenBenji  Thanks for nice answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, theoretically you can mix.

No, you might encounter security issues - specifically reflected XSS - if untrusted user's input -e.g. {{1+2}} - are returned as part of server's response and rendered within Angular's template since that expression will be parsed by angular unwittingly.

See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5601
For a similar discussion

From angular documentation:
In general, we recommend against this because it can create unintended XSS vectors.

However, it's ok to mix server-side templating in the bootstrap template (index.html) as long as user input cannot be used on the server to output html that would then be processed by Angular in a way that would allow for arbitrary code execution.

For instance, you can use server-side templating to dynamically generate CSS, URLs, etc, but not for generating templates that are bootstrapped/compiled by Angular.